# Finding out FileMaker runtime file passwords

Tags: runtime, filemaker, forgot-password

Good evening!

I have a FileMaker runtime application that I would like to modify, but I have prevented changes with a password, which I have forgotten.

Is there any way to get it back?
p.s: I don't have the original FileMaker file, just the Runtime one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you realize that any answer that would be useful to you would also be useful to someone who wants to commit a crime by breaking into a file that does not belong to them?

Comment: The runtime file can also be opened in FileMaker Pro if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the Admin account when you create the runtime... there is not a path back.

Also, note what @michael.hor257k mentioned. It may be your file and your IP... but we have no way to verify that.